# How do I add a PATH to my Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, android

I followed the tutorials and did this:

```
sudo vi /etc/paths

/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/Applications/Android\ Development\ Kit/sdk/platform-tools
```

Even after I do this, I type "adb", and it still does not work.

However, if I cd into `/Applications/Android\ Development\ Kit/sdk/platform-tools/` and then do `./adb` it works.

How can I add the path?

Comment: 1) Did you start a new shell after changing the path? (The old shell will not suddenly use the new path. Login scripts are usually only read on [shell] start. So start a new shell and try "adb". 

2) What happens it you go to a shell and type `export PATH="/Applications/Android\ Development\ Kit/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH"` followed by `adb`?

3) Sanity check: What is "it still does not work"? I am guessing you mean that the shell returns a command not found, but could you make that explicit?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to re-source your system profile by either restarting or using the numbered items below.

Other options include:

To do this temporarily, you can do:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/new/source"
```

Or permanently I'd suggest you add it to your user's configs by adding the above to your `~/.bash_profile` (rather than having it in the system path).

Once done, source the file for your session with either of these:

1. `source ~/.bash_profile`
2. `. ~/.bash_profile`

Also, to ensure that the tools are executable, you need to `chmod` them.

1. Navigate back to the tools directory (with adb) in `Terminal`
2. Run `chmod +x adb` (and do for whatever else you need, such as `fastboot`).

Now when you are not directly in that folder and your `path` is correct, you can just type `adb` (since typing `./adb` elsewhere will try to launch `adb` from the current working directory)

Answer (score 1):

Changing your $PATH via CLI is impermanent and probably not what you want. It'll only last for the session you're in. Depending on your shell, you're going to have to find one of these:

```
~/.profile
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashrc
~/.zshrc
# etc.
```

`~/.bash_profile` should work for bash. If you're on a zshell like iTerm, you'll have to edit `~/.zshrc`, etc. Here's an example of what it might look like:

```
# Customize to your needs...
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/scala-2.10.3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

So just a colon-delimited list of paths, really.

When you save it, you'll have to run it for use in the current session by issuing `. ~/.bash_profile`, `. ~/.zshrc`, or whatever shell you're using. You defaults should be saved from there on out, assuming you've edited the right file. You could also use an alias instead, like

```
alias emacs="/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/bin/emacs-24.3"
```

if you're only interested in one specific thing.

Comment: Mac runs a login shell by default for each new terminal window, so (assuming Bash and that the OP hasn't changed anything - which seems likely per the question), they would need to use `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.profile`.

Comment: Ah, alright. I use zsh. Edited.